# How to recognize if a variable contains a newline character in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, newline

I have a procedure which takes 2 variables as input, one among them may have string characters separated by enter or space.

Space however is easy to figure out, but how to we figure out if the variable has a newline character in it.

I have tried using `chr(10)` but no use, because I have to recognize if the strings are separated by a newline character. By the way even `chr(10)` doesn't work to insert string divided with space.

```
select 'ABC' || chr(10) || 'DEF' as c from dual
```

I currently have no such variable as input so can't even experiment to narrow down to some solutions, Also the above query isn't running fine, I mean it's not giving output like below.

```
ABC
DEF
```

I have also searched for different oracle documentation, but didn't find any.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **new line** depends on the **Operating system**. In **Unix** based OS, it is `CHR(10)`, in **Windows** it is `CHR(13)` **followed by** `CHR(10)`.

You could use either of the following:

- `LIKE '%'||chr(10)||'%'`
- `INSTR(column_name, chr(10)) > 0`

Let's look at test cases in Windows OS:

### **SQL**

**Using LIKE**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'ABC' || chr(10) || 'DEF' AS c FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'PQR' || ' ' || 'XYZ' AS c FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'QWE' || CHR(13) || 'RTY' AS c FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'no_space' AS c FROM dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE c LIKE '%'||chr(10)||'%';

C
--------
ABC
DEF


SQL>
```

**Using INSTR**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'ABC' || chr(10) || 'DEF' AS c FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'PQR' || ' ' || 'XYZ' AS c FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'QWE' || CHR(13) || 'RTY' AS c FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'no_space' AS c FROM dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE INSTR(c, chr(10)) > 0;

C
--------
ABC
DEF


SQL>
```

### **PL/SQL**

**Using LIKE**

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    c VARCHAR2(100);
  3  BEGIN
  4    c:='ABC' || chr(10) || 'DEF';
  5    IF c LIKE '%'||chr(10)||'%' THEN
  6      dbms_output.put_line('found chr(10)');
  7    ELSE
  8      dbms_output.put_line('not found');
  9    END IF;
 10  END;
 11  /
found chr(10)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**Using INSTR**

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    c VARCHAR2(100);
  3  BEGIN
  4    c:='ABC' || chr(10) || 'DEF';
  5    IF INSTR(c, chr(10)) > 0 THEN
  6      dbms_output.put_line('found chr(10)');
  7    ELSE
  8      dbms_output.put_line('not found');
  9    END IF;
 10  END;
 11  /
found chr(10)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi Lalit, thanks for your very elaborative solution. When I query the select with char(10) I don't see the results ABC and DEF in two different lines, but when I run it inside a pl/sql anonymous block I can see the DBMS output of the two string ABC and DEF in to different line ..... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user2404193 You will see that in both SQL and PL/SQL. Use SQL*Plus. If you are using any GUI based tool like SQL Developer, TOAD etc. you might not see the new line in **query output**. Execute it as script, and see in the **script output**. Please mark it as answered, would help others.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table sample (a varchar2(100));
insert into sample (a) values ('HI_next_line
hello_next_line
hello2');
insert into sample (a) values ('singleline1');
insert into sample (a) values ('singleline2');

SQL> select * from sample;

A
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
HI_next_line
hello_next_line
hello2

singleline1
singleline2

SQL> select *
  2  from sample
  3  where instr(a, chr(10)) > 0;

A
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
HI_next_line
hello_next_line
hello2
```